# Spring MVC: Log Controller paths without params

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to add some metric gathering to a Spring MVC app. Lets say I have a controller whose mapping is:

```
 /User/{username}/Foobar
```

I want to gather metrics on all controller mapping invocations with the path. Right now I can create a handler/interceptor and look at the requests but that will give me:

```
/User/Charlie/Foobar
```

Which is not what I want. I want the controller mapping itself to log. and I don't want to have to add something to every controller. I'd also rather not use AOP if I can help it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Spring hangs the best matching controller pattern on the request itself. You can get this from within a handlerinterceptor like this:

```
 (String)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: Much easier, definitively.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two choices:

1. It seems to me the results of the matching are obtained in the class [`org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/v3.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java), which logs the patterns obtained (see line 266). I'd try enabling logging for that class and see if the output is helpful for your purposes.
2. (Complicated)

   Extending [`org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/v3.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java) to override the `lookupHandler` method inherited from `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` and logging/registering what you need. Accoding to [this class documentation](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/v3.0.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java#L40), you can register a different one so that the `DispatcherServlet` uses your version.

   In Spring 3.2.x `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` is deprecated so, a different class would have to be used.